# Is there any way to get name of the client without prompting it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, identity

I want any client (within a certain domain) be able to open my Asp.net MVC Web Application (which also runs on IIS on a machine withit that domain) provide its default user's name, which is what he has logged into his windows account.

I have tried setting Anon auth off and on, I have also enabled the Windows Auth on IIS and yet I either get no user name at all, or the browser (last stable chrome) asks the user for credentials. But I want the default windows credentials, that's all!

What should I do to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply configuration at the browser level.

For IE you need the site in the Intranet Zone and ensure the *Automatic logon with current user name and password* option is set.

For FireFox: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris

Chrome inherits from the same IE zone settings.